# migrate from wamp 32bit to wamp64bit

Tags: localhost, wamp, wampserver

I had windows7 32bit now I've installed windows10 64bit.
Now I want to install 64bit version of wamp but my old wamp Doesn't work.
So I cant create backup from my databases.
(my 32bit version of wamp was wamp3 and now I want to install 64bit version of wamp3)
Please tell me how can I install 64bit version of wamp and move my data to it?

Comment: So you still have the old 32bit wamp folder somewhere right? Where was it originally installed and where is it now please?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for your comment. It was originally in e:\wamp. after changing the windows I've rename it to:e:\old wamp and new wamp address is e:\wamp.